# cloud run billing - execution time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run, billing

I have been using cloud run on GCP for several years.  I recently moved a service over from AWS Lambda, which costs me like 10 dollars a month, but on cloud run it went to 50 dollars per day.  The cloud run service is simply a background worker that should ideally run for 3 minutes max.  It loads, schedules, and summarizes jobs. If there are 50 jobs, it should run 50 background workers so it can bursts, which cloud run complains that it cannot allocate quickly enough.  Since I use a distributed lock, there should be only 50 workers running regardless.

I tried to figure out the costs breakdown and GCP in my experience does not provide any defaults.  I click on the costs breakdown and it just shows me a graph of the monthly costs going from 50 dollars to 800 dollars per month.  There is no costs breakdown.  I'll try to implement labels, but in general, how do I determine the costs break down for cloud run.  AWS lambda is simple because it essentially reduces to execution costs especially within the same VPC.

Besides labels, how do I determine the costs for cloud run?  When I drill down further is this CPU allocation that is huge costs, both in tier 2 and standard tier?

Any suggestions or help would be great :)

Comment: We would need more details on what you configure, how often request arrive, etc.

Comment: thanks.  i just spoke to gcp support chat.  they implemented this tier 2 cpu pricing on november 25th, exactly when i saw a spike in my billing.

Comment: what also added to the costs was my timeout.  i'm not sure if this is new, but i recently saw an allocation error on cloud run during bursts.  it basically cannot allocate.  the agent told me: "Failing to send an HTTP response may result in an execution timeout where you will be charged for the entire duration of the timeout. "

Comment: i had put my timeout at 1 hour though my worker runs for only like 3 minutes.  this compounds to a lot of my money since invocations can happen ever 3-10 minutes.  if a allocaion failure happens, then i get charged for the entire hour.

Comment: i also started seeing allocation capacity issues with google compute.  i don't know what's happening with gcp.

Comment: You talk about background process, but do you send a HTTP response before the end of the background processes? In addition, why did you set the timeout to 1H and not only 5 minutes? Finally, you have tiering in Cloud Run, according to your region (some are more expensive than others)

Comment: sorry, from my understanding, the http is how you invoke the run.  for me, it's similar to a fargate task, but maybe it needs to return a 200?  i had set it 1H because in the past, it would cut the background worker while running, leaving my "job" in an unknown state.  in the effort to provide some overhead, i had set it to one hour since i figure it would end before that.  the job was modified to take the http request for cloud run, but the entry point is typically like a cmd in a docker container.  thus it operates like a fargate task.

Comment: i choose cloud run b/c pub/sub is already integrating with cloud run.  aws requires a lambda bridge to invoke the fargate function.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I am noticing this too. Just started out with Cloud Run Jobs. I'm in my free credits period, but Google's advertised pricing does not correlate with what they charge. I run a few jobs that take a few minutes each, but my timeouts are set to 30 minutes while in testing so they don't crash. Google seems to be charging me for the full wall time period instead of the 2-3 minutes that the containers actually run.

This is bad, bad, bad.

Not only is GCP way more complicated than any other provider (don't get me started on "Workload Identity Federation" and their "Identity and Access Management", which make AWS look easy -- I don't need those as a small business but they are forced on me anyway), but now it seems the pricing they advertise is not what you get.

Comment: i'm coming off of cloud run completely.  to be fair, it's pretty good for businesses that require a single global network since google owns it.  but it's not meant for small businesses where every charge hurts.